# Testing ServiceLoader in Eclipse Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, plugins, serviceloader

I have four Eclipse plugin projects (create a new Java Project, right-click, configure, Convert to Plugin Project) in my workspace. The first (`my.runtime`) contains an interface (`MyFactoryInterface`) and a class (`MyClient`) that defines a method (`List<String> getAllFactoryNames()`) that loads all implementations of that interface via `java.util.ServiceLoader` and calls a method (`String getName()`) on them, collecting the results and returning them in a list.

To test that class, I have a JUnit test in the second project (`my.runtime.test`, set up with `my.runtime` as Fragment-Host), checking if the name returned by a dummy implementation(`MyDummy`, returning `"Dummy"`) I have in the `my.runtime.test` project is in the list returned by `MyClient.getAllFactoryNames()`. So far, it works fine.

In the third project (`my.extension`, with `my.runtime` as dependency) I have a class (`MyHello`) that uses the names returned by `MyClient.getAllFactoryNames()` to return a list of greetings (`"Hello "+name`).

Again, to test this, I have a project (`my.extension.test`, with `my.extension` as Fragment-Host) containing another Implementation (`MyWorld`, returning `"World"` as name) and a JUnit test case checking if `"Hello World"` is in the greetings returned by `MyHello.getGreetings()`. This test fails, as MyClient still only finds the `MyDummy` implementation, and not the `MyWorld` implementation. Both implementations are accompanied by matching entries in `META-INF/services/my.runtime.MyFactoryInterface` files.

I currently use the following code to load the implementations:

```
ServiceLoader<MyFactoryInterface> myFactoryLoader = ServiceLoader.load(MyFactoryInterface.class);
    for (MyFactoryInterface myFactory : myFactoryLoader) {
```

I know that I can supply a ClassLoader as a second argument to `ServiceLoader.load`, but I have no idea how to get one that knows all plugin projects... any suggestions? Or is ServiceLoader not the right tool for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone stumbles over the same problem: the combination of `ServiceLoader.load(MyFactoryInterface.class, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())` in `MyClient` and `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(MyWorld.class.getClassLoader());` in the second test did the job.

Comment: I believe my problem is rather specific, as the runtime is, as the name suggests, a project that is used by other programs at runtime, idependent of eclipse but is also a plugin project because it is used as well by other plugins to create data for the runtime programs... which are tested in eclipse and call the runtime code during the tests.